# Voltage Dropout plot in LTSpice

Tags: ltspice, ldo

I am trying to achieve this plot in LTspice from the datasheet of [LT1762](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LT1762.pdf). (I am a beginner trying to understand how this works)
[image]

My schematic is as follows:
[image]

The output I get is this.
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My main goal is to try to plot **Dropout Voltage vs. Output Current** . I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What is the Y-axis in your simulation result?

Comment: it was V(in,out) i.e the difference in the input and output voltages.

Comment: I am getting similar error while plotting the quiescent current vs input voltage graph.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the **.step temp -50 125 50** command. What this command will do is run a series of plots from -50\$^\circ\$C to 125\$^\circ\$C in 50\$^\circ\$C steps. Each value in a **.step** command is discrete and will run the simulation over again plotting another trace in a new color with just that parameter changed, it is not a continuous sweep like a DC sweep. While the **.step** command editor will let you set a 'sweep' with **temp** as the parameter it will not give you a continuous variable to plot against. If you change the Y axis to plot **temp** it will show you the initial value \$\pm\$0.1 as you can see on your graph.

In order to recreate the original chart you would need to sweep the temperature and plot with that as the Y axis, I'm not aware of a way to do this in LTspice, there may not be a way. I believe the temperature parameter has to be set at the beginning of a simulation sweep and can not be changed mid sweep, you can only step it over multiple sweeps.

Also in your other **.step** command I think you can leave out **dec**, that's for doing a logarithmic step by decade and requires a lower limit, upper limit, and the number of steps per decade as parameters whereas you have a list of values.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same circuit at my end and I get 2.5V output. I did the DC sweep analysis instead. You can see the output below:

[image]